# Undefined local variable or method "#name of method" for#

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I know this is a common error, but my problem is quite difference. I had this code: `<% accessible_prefectures.each do |prefecture| -%>`
when I put it in a file located in products directory it run correctly(on PC interface). However, when I copy this code to other file in mobile directory(to display on mobile interface) it throw the error:

```
Undefined local variable or method 'accessible_prefectures' for#...
```

I didn't understand why while in this directory it ran correctly, but in other one error occur. So can someone explain it for me?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you're referencing the `accessible_prefectures` variable.  The "PC interface" controller (or view) has passed that variable to the view as a local variable.

The mobile interface does not pass that variable to the view/partial that your code is in.